# Zeros complement of ANSI C89

Tags: c, ansi-c

When compliment of 0 was found it turned out to be -1. Why the complement of 0 is -1?  Is it always -1 or does it depend on compiler?

Comment: What do you mean by "complement" or "compliment" here?  Do you mean bitwise negation?

Comment: It means the operation of ~ operator

Comment: So yes, bitwise negation.

Answer (score 2):

The bitwise negation of 0, written in C as `~0`, is -1 only if the compiler uses [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent signed integers. So, it's a result of the way the compiler represents numbers and is not generally "true".

Answer (score 0):

It is -1 in [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). The compiler is free to choose other representations.

Comment: ...but no compiler in use today actually does.  :)

Comment: @John There are still legacy systems that use one's complement, but they are getting more and more rare. I usually assume two's complement when I code C. Using constructs newer than C89 is probably a greater reduction in portability than assuming two's complement.